# Best way to decorate databound text in a wpf TextBlock

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textblock

Let's say I have some multiline text that I'd like to format, and let's also say that it's databound.  So, in XAML:

```
<TextBlock TextWrap="Wrap">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run TextWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
        <Run TextStyle="Italic Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

Now, this doesn't work because Run's Text isn't a dependency property.  So, I'm wondering, what is the best way to style inline databound text like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround posted [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/data_binding_in_a_flowdocument.html). It basically involves subclassing Run to be bindable. Works though.

Comment: Dead links on that page to  BindableRun class :(